# How to shorten a video?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, edit-mode, video

Make a Livestream shorter? Is this possible?
I am learning Blender still, so I don't know all the shortcuts and quickies on the software. With that said I don't know if this is even possible for Blender?
How could I make a Livestream footage shorter, compressed like? I want to make a SpeedPaint video for at least 15 minutes or less. I do not want to show an entire 2hr and 28 minute video.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: You want to speed up a video record of you screen? Why do you want to use blender for that?

Answer (score 2):

Add a Speed control strip.

[image]

Then change the speed in the multiply speed control.

[image]

Then just adjust the render range of your project.